# android : how to restrict third party memory cleaning apps cleaning my application memory

Tags: android

I have an android application which will do some recording work. when I open the clean master memory boosting application while my app is running and boost the memory, my application is being killed by the OS. So, how can restrict the clean master access my applications memory.

Thanks in advance.